# Graphicsmagick image isn't saving properly?

Tags: c, graphicsmagick

I'm having a problem with GraphicsMagick. I'm rearranging the pixels in an image and trying to save it, but the resulting image is always the same. How do I get it to update the image before saving?
Here is my code:

```
PixelPacket *write_pixels = SetImagePixelsEx(
    image,
    0, // x
    0, // y
    w, // columns
    h, // rows
    &exception
);
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    printf("%hhu -> ", write_pixels[y * w].red);
    printf("%hhu -> ", pixels[y][0].red);
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        write_pixels[x + y * w] = pixels[y][x];
    }
    printf("%hhu\n", write_pixels[y * w].red);
}
SyncImagePixelsEx(image, &exception);    

strcpy(image->filename, outfile);
if (!WriteImage(imageInfo, image)) {
    CatchException(&image->exception);
    return 1;
}
```

I print some output to make sure it's working. Here is some of the output:

```
81 -> 64 -> 64
68 -> 65 -> 65
84 -> 66 -> 66
80 -> 67 -> 67
64 -> 68 -> 68
93 -> 69 -> 69
86 -> 70 -> 70
91 -> 71 -> 71
107 -> 72 -> 72
85 -> 73 -> 73
111 -> 74 -> 74
102 -> 75 -> 75
```

So I know the pixels are getting changed correctly. And the [docs](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/api/pixel_cache.html#setimagepixelsex) say that all I need to update the pixels is `SyncImagePixelsEx()`, which I use. Why is this not updating the image when I save it?

I have checked everything, but every time, the image that gets saved to a new filename always looks identical to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of frustration, I finally came across a solution. Creating a new image with the pixel data works:

```
Image *new_image;
new_image = ConstituteImage(
    image->columns, // width
    image->rows, // height
    "RGBO", // order of pixel array
    CharPixel, // type
    write_pixels, // pixels
    &exception
);

strcpy(new_image->filename, outfile);
if (!WriteImage(image_info, new_image)) {
    CatchException(&new_image->exception);
    return 1;
}
```